# Can't compile the code with getting the value from JsonObject

Tags: java, android-studio, google-places-api, object-property

I use Volley library to make API request to Google Places.
The response is an object like this:

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
          "address":  "Wood Quay, Dublin, Ireland",
          "name":     "Christ Church Cathedral",
          "place_id": "ChIJGw9ASiYMZ0gRy9yiaCZxNZI",
        },
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Inside the `Response.Listener` I need to access the "results" array.
I try to get the JSONArray with name "results" as follows:

```
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_URL, null,
        new Response.Listener <JSONObject> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                // THE PROBLEM IS HERE - WON'T COMPILE !!!
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //
            }
        });
```

But I see an error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `response.getJSONArray("results");` throws the `JSONException`. You need to handle that exception by wrapping `response.getJSONArray("results");` with a try-catch block.

Something like this:

```
 try {
    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
} catch (org.json.JSONException exception) {
    //  handle the exception
}
```